# helping in understand this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, compounds, conjugations

He was considered by many the greatest of all Arab poets but his own arrogant self-regard for his abilities did not endear him to other writers and they **looked for a source for his verse.** **Just as there were collections detailing every possible rhetorical figure used in literature emerged as well as how to write guides.**

A. *looked for a source for his verse*

Firstly, I cannot get what is the relation between this sentence--*A*-- and its previous sentence--*his own arrogant self-regard for his abilities did not endear him to other writers and they.*

...................................................

B. Just as there were collections detailing every possible rhetorical figure used in literature emerged as well as how to write guides.

First off, would you show me which phrase(s) this conector **as well as** connects together?

What is more, I really cannot get the concept of the sentence--B.

Comment: Honestly, these sentences doesn't make much sense... could you post the source information? Are these sentences actually consecutive in the source material?  If not, you probably want to make this two questions.

Comment: The current version of this page on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_literature#Literary_criticism does not actually contain part B of your quote.  Please be sure to cite your sources!

Comment: It's better to wait until OP provides with some more info - source or whatever necessary or those what @Catija asked for that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context helps quite a bit for this question.  The [full paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_literature#Literary_criticism) reads (to a slightly broader degree:

> Plagiarism also became a significant idea exercising the critics' concerns. The works of al-Mutanabbi were particularly studied with this concern. He was considered by many the greatest of all Arab poets but his own arrogant self-regard for his abilities did not endear him to other writers and they *looked for a source for his verse*.

This is talking about [plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism). What it seems to be implying is that al-Mutanabbi was such an arrogant person about his own abilities that the other writers possibly disliked him and wanted to find proof that he hadn't actually written the poetry he claimed to have written. So, *looked for a source for his work* means they were researching old texts trying to find the poems he claimed to have written.

This is the equivalent of a modern professor Googling the content of an essay you turn in to check if you actually wrote it yourself or copied it from some other source.

---

Part B actually appears to be quite different on the Wikipedia page than what you quote:

> Just as there were collections of facts written about many different subjects, numerous collections detailing every possible rhetorical figure used in literature emerged as well as how to write guides.

This, I think, is just a poorly written, overcomplicated example of why Wikipedia isn't the best source for serious research.

This sentence starts by saying:

> Collections of facts were written about many different subjects.

This is just a simple statement. It may not even relate to Arabic Literature alone... there are thousands of reference books out there on many topics. This can honestly probably be removed from the sentence.

In the rest of the sentence, the sentence lists a couple of types of *collections of fact* that relate to the subject of the article:

> Collections about rhetorical figures used in literature
>
> Guides about how to write in this style.

The problem with this sentence is that **emerged** got plopped in a very ... nonsensical spot.

Emerged is the verb here.  The word choice is used appropriately but the placement is very unusual. **as well as** is transitively tying *emerged* to both  of the parts of the statement:

- Collections about rhetorical figures used in literature emerged.
- How-to-write guides emerged.

The [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emerge) of *emerged* being used here is:

> to become known or apparent

Though, in this case, it could possibly have the meaning *came into common use* or *came into existence*.

I've been attempting to rewrite the sentence and failing because the meaning of the sentence is not clear, so rewriting it has a tendency to change its meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am, however, still wondering what "emerge" is here?

Comment: @nima Ok, I've restructured the second part and included a section on *emerge*.